# Visual Studio 2019 fails to load Template

Tags: visual-studio, templates

Some months ago, I wrote an MVVM-Template for Visual Studio 2019. It worked fine, I placed it into `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates` and worked with it for a while.

Now I needed to reset my PC and so I downloaded VS19 again. I stored the template on an external server, so I downloaded it again and placed it into the ProjectTemplates Folder. But it didn't show up. I looked into `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Locations`, where the Project-template-folder was the same as the one where my template is at the moment.

After that I checked the `.vstemplate-file`, but there was nothing wrong with it. I tried everything what Microsoft told me to do when the Template doesn't show up but now I don't know what else to try

Edit: I looked into `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0[MyID]\InstalledTemplates.json` where my template is named. but it still doesn't show up when creating a new project

Edit 2: Strangely, after running `devenv /updateConfiguration` in the developer console, it worked. But normally that command creates a log file, but it didn't, instead the template now shows up